# $\lim_{\eta\to 0^+}\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{2}f(x+\eta)dx=\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{2}f(x)dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, limits, continuity

> If $f(x)$ is a real valued continuous function on $[-5,5]$ and $0<\eta<\frac{1}{2}$ be arbitrarily small, then prove that $$\lim_{\eta\to 0^+}\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{2}f(x+\eta)dx= \int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{2}f(x)dx  $$ given that the limit and integrals exist and are finite.

I tried as follows: Since $f(x)$ is continuous on $[-5,5]$ , so it is uniformly continuous on $[-5,5]$ and for every $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $$|f(x+\eta)-f(x)|<\frac{\varepsilon}{1.5} \ \ \text{when} \ \ 0<\eta<\delta $$

Now we have by the triangle inequality $$\left|\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{2}f(x+\eta)dx- \int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{2}f(x)dx\right|\leq  \int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{2}\left|f(x+\eta) -f(x)\right|dx $$
So we get $$\left|\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{2}f(x+\eta)dx- \int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{2}f(x)dx\right|<\left(\frac{\varepsilon}{1.5}\right)(1.5)=\varepsilon $$ when $0<\eta<\delta$.

Your comments are valuable and are welcome.

Comment: Nav, if you want to edit your attempt, I suggest you *add* whatever you need below the original one instead of changing it; so that you won't change your post fundamentally. Answers below may depend on your original version.

Comment: @user1046533 Yes but is it something different now? I have just changed continuity by uniform continuity in the attempt

Answer (score 1):

What you need is the *uniform* continuity of the function $f$ so that your last estimate is valid:

> for every $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that *for every* $x\in[0.5,2]$, $$|f(x+\eta)-f(x)|<\frac{\varepsilon}{1.5} \ \ \text{when} \ \ 0<\eta<\delta $$

Comment: Thank you. But then is Uniform continuity enough? Because we have things like the Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem which needs extra conditions. So DCT gets replaced here by just requiring uniform continuity?

Comment: @Nav: we are proving the limit from scratch by doing estimates and not using DCT. So all you need is the uniform estimate.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So we need uniform continuity of $f(x)$ over $[0.5,2]$ or over some larger closed interval?

Comment: @Nav you already have uniform continuity on $[-5,5]$ which contains $[0.5,2]$; this guarantees the estimate in this posted answer.

Comment: I am asking that just continuity on interval $[0.5,2]$ (which implies uniform continuity) is enough right?

Comment: @Nav: you would have trouble at the end point since $2+\eta\not\in[0.5,2]$; but that's okay since $f$ is continuous on the whole interval.

Comment: So what is the smallest closed interval on which if function is uniformly continuous then we have the required limit?

Comment: @Nav: $[-5,5]$ is given in the assumption. You extra question is an interesting one to have another post.

Comment: Does $\eta$ depends on $\varepsilon$ or does $\eta$ depends on $\delta$?

Comment: @Nav: it would be helpful for you to go over the definition of uniform continuity. In the estimate above, the quantity $\delta$ depends on $\epsilon$ and $\eta$ satisfies $0<\eta<\delta$.

Comment: Thanks. So if $\eta$ depends on $\varepsilon$, then also the proof will work?

Comment: @Nav: I don't understand your question. "$\eta$ depends on $\epsilon$" means the order of the phrase "for every $\epsilon$ there exists $\delta$".

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer approach without uniform continuity, but with extreme value theorem (just a preference, seems simpler to me).

Let $M = \max |f|([-5, 5])$.
For $0 < \eta <\frac 1 2$ we can make substitution $u = x + \eta$ and write
$$
\int_{\frac 1 2}^2 f(x + \eta) \operatorname d \!x
=\int_{\frac 1 2 + \eta}^{2+ \eta} f(x) \operatorname d \!x.
$$
Now we have
$$\begin{align}
\left| \int_{\frac 1 2}^2 f(x + \eta) \operatorname d \!x
- \int_{\frac 1 2}^2 f(x) \operatorname d \!x \right|
&=
\left| -\int_{\frac 1 2}^{\frac 1 2 + \eta} f(x) \operatorname d \!x
+ \int_{2}^{2 + \eta} f(x) \operatorname d \!x \right| \\
&\leq
\int_{\frac 1 2}^{\frac 1 2 + \eta} |f(x)| \operatorname d \!x
+ \int_{2}^{2 + \eta} |f(x)| \operatorname d \!x \\
&\leq 2\eta M.
\end{align}
$$
If we let $\eta \to 0^+$, we see that integrals converge to the given.

Comment: Thanks. But where did you use extreme value theorem?

Comment: What is the smallest closed inverval which contains $[0.5,2]$ , so that the result hold? $[-5,5]$ is too large.

Comment: I used extreme value theorem for continuous function $|f|$ right at the beginning to define $M$. This solution would be valid if $f$ was continuous on any interval $[1/2, 2 + \varepsilon]$ for some $\varepsilon > 0$. We would just make sure that $\eta < \varepsilon$. Solution would not be valid on $[1/2, 2]$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But how did we get that $M$ is independent of $\eta$? What will happen if we have a case where $M$ depends on $\eta$?

Comment: $M$ depends on $\varepsilon$. The changed version would be $M = \max |f|([\frac 1 2 , 2 + \varepsilon])$. This value exists thanks to the extreme value theorem. We only pick $\eta$ after $\varepsilon$ is established.

Comment: Why $M$ depends only on $\varepsilon$? Why do we pick $\eta $ after $\varepsilon$ is established?

Comment: If we have $f$ that is defined on $[1/2, \varepsilon + 2]$ and continuous there, then if you think that $\varepsilon$ is fixed then $M$ depends only on $f$. I just wanted to point out, that $\varepsilon$ could be arbitrarily small, and that usually makes us think that it approaches zero, which is not the case here. However if $f$ was defined on some bigger interval, then we could artificially shrink it, and get possibly smaller $M$.  We have to make sure that $\eta + 2$ is in our domain to be able to write integral, so $\eta \leq \varepsilon$ is forced.